# V-model array item cannot updating in spite of having reference

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My main purpose is collecting the requested quantity for multiple inventories(future usage).

*** I tried to make a counter for referenced v-models.**
I made out something like this. But it doesn't work:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      counter: []
    },
    methods: {
      increment(x) { 
        this.counter[x]++
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i in 2">
  <div><input type="text" v-model="counter[i]"></div>
  <button v-on:click="increment(i)">Increment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a different way to do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work for two reasons:

A) Your array is empty, so when you use `counter[i]` as v-model you're using `undefined`, which can't be incremented.

B) You're mutating your array by index, which doesn't work well with Vue. To mutate arrays, you should use methods like `push` or `splice`.

To fix your code, you must address your two issues. That is, you must initialize your array with numeric values and mutate your array via functions, like this:

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    counter: [0, 0]
},
methods: {
    increment(x) { 
        this.counter.splice(x, 1, this.counter[x] + 1);
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(val, i) in counter">
        <div><input type="text" v-model="counter[i]"></div>
        <button v-on:click="increment(i)">Increment</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I also changed your template to use `(val, i) in counter` instead of `i in 2`. That is done so that you can access your array from the starting index. `val` is the element, `i` is the index, so you use `i` to increment your array.

Also note the use of `splice`. What it does is replacing the `x`th element of your array with it's own `x`th element, but incremented.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be beautiful, but it works:

```js
var vm = {
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counterel1: 0,
    counterel2: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    increment(x) {
      this.counter[x-1]++;
      console.log(this.counter);
    }
  }
}

vm.data.counter = [vm.data.counterel1, vm.data.counterel2];

new Vue(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i in 2">
    <div><input type="text" v-model="counter[i]"></div>
    <button v-on:click="increment(i)">Increment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```